# jQuery Timed Counter from a user supplied interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

My ultimate goal is to create a timer that produces a sound at an interval supplied by the user.  For example, they input 10 into a field, and then a beep occurs every 10 seconds.  Right now, I'm just having trouble with getting the setInterval to display the effect in a span.  Any help getting me back on track is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<div id="ping_div">
  <p>
    Enter the desired interval in milliseconds to sound ping noise. <br />
    <input id="ping_val" type="text" /> <input id="set_ping" type="button" value="Submit" /><span id="ping_alert"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
<input id="go" type="button" value="Click to Start Pings"  />
<span id="progress"></span>
  </p>
</div>


____________________________


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#set_ping').click(function() {
    interval = $('#ping_val').val();
    $('#ping_alert').text('The ping will sound every ' + interval + ' milliseconds.');
  });

  $('#go').click(function() {  
    setInterval(timer, interval); 
  });

  function timer() {
    var base = base + interval;
    $('#progress').text(base);
  }

});
```

Comment: which part are you having problems with?  are you events firing?  are you checking for errors?  are you doing any sort of debugging?

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/PxENF/

Comment: You are working with a string, not a number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as-is, but it would be more obvious if you made a few changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/PxENF/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var base = 0, interval = 1000; // <-----
  $('#set_ping').click(function() {
    interval = parseInt($('#ping_val').val(),10); // <-----
    $('#ping_alert').text('The ping will sound every ' + interval + ' milliseconds.');
  });

  $('#go').click(function() {  
    setInterval(timer, interval); 
  });

  function timer() {
    base = base + interval; // <-----
    $('#progress').text(base);
  }

});
```

Comment: You should use a radix on the parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#go').click(function() {
    interval = $('#ping_val').val();
    $('#ping_alert').text('The ping will sound every ' + interval + ' milliseconds.');
    setInterval(timer, interval); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the interval self supporting, without declaring global variables:

```
$("#go").click(function() {
    var interval = $("#ping_val").val();
    setInterval(function(){ 
        var progress = $("#progress");
        var html = progress.html();
        var offset = html.length > 0 ? parseInt(html) : 0;
        progress.html(offset + interval);
     }, interval); 
  });
```

Remember, each time you click "go" a new interval is started. These will interfere with eachother. This would be better:

```
var runningInterval = 0;
$("#go").click(function() {
    clearInterval(runningInterval);
    $("#progress").html("0");
    var interval = $("#ping_val").val();
    runningInterval = setInterval(function(){ 
        var progress = $("#progress");
        var html = progress.html();
        var offset = html.length > 0 ? parseInt(html) : 0;
        progress.html(offset + interval);
     }, interval); 
  });
```